# cakephp redirect url behaving strangely

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-routing

I'm not sure exactly where to start looking for how to fix or what it is I need to fix so hopefully someone can give me a pointer.

I have some basic authentication working but the url I want to redirect to is becoming something else along the way. Here's the problem -

I login sucessfully and I want to do this...

```
 'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'account'),
```

with the expected url being

```
 http://localhost/cakephp/users/account
```

but the url that it is actually produced is

```
 http://localhost/cakephp/cakephp/users/account
```

with the accompanying message, of course, 
Error: CakephpController could not be found (which I understand)

Can someone help as to why I've got this doubled up cakephp part in the url? I haven't been messing with any of the routes or anything like that. Is it a configuration issue?

Thanks.
DS

Comment: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3938-this-redirectthis-auth-redirecturl-broken If you're using 2.4 try grabbing the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to latest version.
Problem solved.

DS